# How to sort du -h output?

Tags: bash

```
du --max-depth=1 -h /media/downloads/ | sort -g -r
```

This will not ofcourse sort regarding G, M, K suffixes... Is there any way to solve it as one-line bash command?

Comment: Stop using `-h`. *runs*

Comment: I agree. Use `-m` instead, which should remain readable and enable you to sort numerically (`sort -n`).

Comment: Usually this kind of answer implies to `not possible` or `efforts not worth to...`.

Comment: The [same question](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size) with many more answers.

Answer (score 27):

Have you tried `sort -h -r` instead? My Linux is RHEL 6.1. `sort` version 8.4.

Comment: `-h` is available on my Linux, but not on my Mac OS X. It appears this option is ideal, but not portable.

Comment: Conclusion - whenever your options are not working, try with the next letter from the ASCII set... :) @Pablo - sort -h available in sort from [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), I have v8.5.

Comment: @Pablo Actually, it does work on Ubuntu (11.10 here). It belongs to the package `coreutils`, in case that's not installed by default I would guess it is).

Comment: `sort: invalid option -- 'h'` 10.04 here

Comment: @Pablo Time for the upgrade :) Try to upgrade `coreutils` only if that's an option for you.

Comment: @icyrock.com: sorry man, I don't want to alter system only for this small task :)

Comment: @Pablo Completely agree - I was more on the of the idea that you can upgrade and get all new improvements and new bugs completely free :) Sorry to hear that it's not supported on the version you have...

Comment: @icyrock.com: it's ok, not a disaster :)

Comment: heh, I've earned nice question badge for off-topic... nice